# How to upload a zip-file from my Android App to Amazon AWS?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload a zip file from my Android App to Amazon AWS. I can I do it? I don't even know how to start. Do you recommend to upload it in Amazon S3 or is there a better solution? I think DynamoDb is not possible, because it does not allow zip files.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be write a Lambda function and use API Gateway to expose the Lambda function as a Restful endpoint. Then from your Mobile app, you can do a POST to that Restful endpoint and pass the data. The Lambda function then reads that data and uploads the data to an Amazon S3 bucket using the Amazon S3 service's **PutObject** operation.

And yes you are correct in that you would not place a binary ZIP file in an Amazon DynamoDB table.